# integration failed with react and php for post data

Tags: php, reactjs

i'm trying to store data in mysql using axios in reactjs, whenever I post data its saved twice in database. one raw blank and another raw saves actual value. and when I fetch data its return value 3 times, how can I solve this problem?

Here My Post Request

```
axios.post('http://localhost/scripts/student/signup.php', {
 data:{
     "rollnumber":rno,
     "firstname":fname,
     "lastname":lname,
     "username":uname,
     "password":pass,},
   headers:headers
       }).then(response=>{
            console.log(response);                      
       })
```

"signup.php file"

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);
$rno = $dbdata["data"]["rollnumber"];
$fname = $dbdata["data"]["firstname"];
$lname = $dbdata["data"]["lastname"];
$uname = $dbdata["data"]["username"];
$pass = $dbdata["data"]["password"];
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","connectivity");     
if($link==false){
  die("ERROR: Could not connect." .mysqli_connect_error());}
else{}
$response = "";
$sql = "INSERT INTO signup (rollnumber, fname, lname, uname, password) 
VALUES('$rno', '$fname', '$lname', '$uname', '$pass')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
$response = array("success" =>true,"message"=>"Saved Successfully");}
else{
$response = array("Fail" =>true,"message"=>"Data Not Saved Successfully");
}
echo json_encode($response);           
?>
```

Output in database

its saves dummy data also

[image]

'fetch.php'

```
`    <?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","connectivity");
if($link==false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect." .mysqli_connect_error());
 }
 else{}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM signup";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))          
    $items[] = $row;
    echo Json_encode($items);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
} else{
    echo "No records matching your query were found.";
}
mysqli_close($
```

here my response from database

[image]

Comment: Are u using redux?which are the action causing this API call?

Comment: no i'm not using redux , its done by simple way with event in onSubmit for form data@RIYAJ KHAN

Comment: Could you please check network tab and tell us wether there Twice API call for saving post data?Otherwise PHP backedn script issue

Comment: ok, thats a problem in API it call twice, can you please tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Definately there are some action doing this on React side.Put breakpoint in API call function and check callstack.Check which are the resources triggering this api call.

Answer (score 0):

I think your default onSubmit action is called from react.js form.

add attribute type to button element inside  element.

```
<form>
  <button onClick={this.SubmitForm}>Submit</button> {/* This will trigger twice, remove this. */}
  <button type="button" onClick={this.SubmitForm}>Submit</button> {/* Add type="button" to prevent default action */}
</form>
```

Comment: i've tried this but it not submit the form and throws error for getting value